# How to adjust position of single node in flow diagram in DiagrammeR?

Tags: r, diagrammer

Q: How can I change the location of a single node in a `DiagrammeR` flow diagram, using the native syntax? Even a hack is fine.

Unexpectedly, the rendering of the second block of code below came out the same as the first. I thought maybe that was because the `x` and `y` arguments only worked with particular `layout` arguments to `render_graph()`. But the rendering didn't change even after I use `render_graph(g,layout="manual")`.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
g <- create_graph(attr_theme="tb")
g <- add_node(g)
g <- add_node(g)
g <- add_node(g)
render_graph(g)
```

```
library(DiagrammeR)
g <- create_graph(attr_theme="tb")
g <- add_node(g)
g <- add_node(g)
g <- add_node(g, node_aes = node_aes(x = 10, y = 10))
render_graph(g)
# Same :(
```

Comment: I don't see how to do what you want.  I think if you want to specify x and y for one node, you'll need to specify them for all nodes.  And then you can't use the `"tb"` theme.

Comment: This old `DiagrammeR` issue includes some code to extract positions from a graph layout:  https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/171 . It might be a start...