# How to place nodes on the same rank in native DiagrammeR?

Tags: r, diagrammer

Q: In `DiagrammeR` native syntax, how does one force certain nodes to be on the same rank?

E.g., below I was able to force nodes 4, 5, 6, 7 onto the same rank by creating an invisible node 2, with invisible edges in and out of it. But this is just a hack. And the resulting diagram is a little off balance. There must be a better way to do this, right?

```
library(DiagrammeR)

g <- create_graph(attr_theme="tb")
g <- add_node(g) # node 1
g <- add_node(g, from=1, node_aes = node_aes(style = "invisible"), edge_aes = edge_aes(style = "invisible", arrowhead = "none")) # node 2, my invisible node
g <- add_node(g, from=1, edge_aes = edge_aes(style = "solid")) # node 3
g <- add_node(g, from=2, edge_aes = edge_aes(style = "invisible", arrowhead = "none")) # node 4
g <- add_node(g, from=2, edge_aes = edge_aes(style = "invisible", arrowhead = "none")) # node 5
g <- add_edge(g, from=1,to=4, edge_aes = edge_aes(style = "solid"))
g <- add_edge(g, from=1,to=5, edge_aes = edge_aes(style = "solid"))
g <- add_node(g, from=3) # node 6
g <- add_node(g, from=3) # node 7
render_graph(g)
```

[image]

Comment: This surely sounds like a duplicate of your other question.

Comment: @IRTFM I think you mean my question [How to adjust position of single node in flow diagram in DiagrammeR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77029460/629000). Def not a duplicate. There, ultimately, I want to place the entire diagram within a single node, by adjusting the node size and location. Here, I really just want to get these nodes on the same rnak.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here is that if you want that level of control of positioning, you have to do all the positioning by yourself.  For example,

```r
library(DiagrammeR)

g <- create_graph()
g <- add_node(g, node_aes = node_aes(x = 0, y = 3)) # node 1
g <- add_node(g, from=1, node_aes = node_aes(x = 0.75, y = 2)) # node 2 (was 3)
g <- add_node(g, from=1, node_aes = node_aes(x = -1.5, y = 1)) # node 3 (was 4)
g <- add_node(g, from=1, node_aes = node_aes(x = -0.5, y = 1)) # node 4 (was 5)
g <- add_node(g, from=2, node_aes = node_aes(x = 0.5, y = 1)) # node 5 (was 6)
g <- add_node(g, from=2, node_aes = node_aes(x = 1.5, y = 1)) # node 6 (was 7)
render_graph(g, width = 400)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There are other graph packages (e.g. `igraph`, `Rgraphviz`) that have functions which do layouts and output the coordinates; perhaps one of those is more flexible than `DiagrammeR` and would allow you to do automatic placement subject to some constraints.  You might even be able to use a different package for the layout, then use the same layout values in `DiagrammeR`.